# cast/ROUND A SUBQUERY

Tags: sql

```
CAST(ROUND(T9.[Price],2)AS NUMERIC(36,2))'Sell_Price',


(SELECT T9.[Price] FROM ITM1 T9 WHERE T9.[PriceList] = '1' and T9.ItemCode = T0.ItemCode )'Trade',
(SELECT T9.[Price] FROM ITM1 T9 WHERE T9.[PriceList] = '8' and T9.ItemCode = T0.ItemCode )'RRP',
```

Hi Experts, How do I CAST/ROUND a subquery so that it produces results in the same format as the first line of SQL code?   The subquery works correctly but I only want to show 2 decimal places but I can't figure how to CAST/ROUND it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the datatype of `Price` and what DBMS are you using? There shouldn't be any reason you can't just place that conversion in the subqueries like `(SELECT CAST(ROUND(T9.[Price],2)AS NUMERIC(36,2)) FROM ITM1 T9 WHERE T9.[PriceList] = '1' and T9.ItemCode = T0.ItemCode )'Trade',` although do you really need the `cast` *and* the `round`?

Comment: It is using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure why the CAST and ROUND are both being used.   I'm trying to work with someone elses code who has left he company.  SQL isn't really my thing as you can probably tell!

Comment: Data type for 'Price' is numeric

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply replace `T9.[Price]` with `CAST(ROUND(T9.[Price],2)AS NUMERIC(36,2))`, so your subqueries will look like:

```
(SELECT CAST(ROUND(T9.[Price],2) AS NUMERIC(36,2)) FROM ITM1 T9 WHERE T9.[PriceList] = '1' and T9.ItemCode = T0.ItemCode )'Trade',
(SELECT CAST(ROUND(T9.[Price],2) AS NUMERIC(36,2)) FROM ITM1 T9 WHERE T9.[PriceList] = '8' and T9.ItemCode = T0.ItemCode )'RRP',
```

If you're okay with a `decimal` instead of a `numeric` you could also consider the following ([since `round` on a `numeric` will return a `decimal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)):

```
(SELECT ROUND(T9.[Price],2) FROM ITM1 T9 WHERE T9.[PriceList] = '1' and T9.ItemCode = T0.ItemCode )'Trade',
(SELECT ROUND(T9.[Price],2) FROM ITM1 T9 WHERE T9.[PriceList] = '8' and T9.ItemCode = T0.ItemCode )'RRP',
```

(but don't do the latter unless you understand why the original code wanted a `numeric`)